# Assuming correct input, can epoll_ctl() with EPOLL_CTL_MOD fail?

Tags: c, linux, epoll

Can epoll_ctl() with EPOLL_CTL_MOD produce `ENOMEM` or `ENOSPC`?

Answer (score 0):

No, according to https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/814a2bf957739f367cbebfa1b60237387b72d0ee/fs/eventpoll.c, the only possible errors are the following:

1. EFAULT
2. EBADF
3. EPERM
4. EINVAL
5. ENOENT